# Storing game data in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, html, game-engine

So basically I have game characters with

```
Gender,

Race,

Items, //this is an array

Skills, //another array

Inventory //another array
```

So I thought of storing them in a json object. But would that be fast?

so in the table would be something like

```
id | js

1  | jsondata
```

Is this a good way to accomplish the saving of data?

Comment: Javascript variables **are** JSON. What you store in a database is something else. Some sort of server-side script translates from database to whatever you send to your client. There are many ways to skin a cat. Be specific.

Comment: Oh yeah, what am I asking. My bad. Well would you think that the way I am trying to do this is a decent way or are there significantly better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few downsides to this approach I can think of off the top of my head:

- *(This item applies to the original question before the edit, where the approach was to store JavaScript code (`var gender='male'; ...`) in the database column)* You are executing data. This basically gives people free reign to inject any code they want into your application if they can modify the blob.
- It requires the JavaScript to be parsed. If later on you decide you wish to run the game in a different, non-js environment (a native or managed app, for example), you will either have to parse the blob, or convert it later.
- The data is not structured, is not editable/retrievable piecemeal, and are of arbitrary length. You have to retrieve and execute the entire blob every time, and in order to save state, you must send and update the entire blob as a single block. If you are using a database it would be much more efficient to save each inventory item as a separate row, for example. When the player uses the item, you can send a single query to update one row and the inventory is immediately changed. With your approach you need to send the entire game state back up to the server.

  This will be counterproductive if you ever want to use the database engine to search. Think leaderboards, statistics, finding who owns which item, etc.

  You also can not use the database engine to maintain data integrity (check or foreign key constraints)
- *(This item applies to the original question before the edit, where the approach was to store JavaScript code (`var gender='male'; ...`) in the database column)* You have to generate the code anyway from existing objects, so why do it on the way in? Or frankly, why execute dynamic code in the first place. If you are loading *data*, then store *data* (i.e. JSON) and parse it.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thank you.

Would it matter if my database is very large

And would it be okay to have a new table for every one-to-many relationship (items, inventory, skills?)

Comment: @user2783087 That's actually exactly the approach I would suggest. An additional benefit is you can later change item properties in one place and have it affect everyone's inventory globally - without having to read, parse, and re-write everyone's blob.